# References for the result that $\sqrt{n}$ is equidistributed mod 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, infinite-sequences

It is not difficult to show (even without Weyl criterion) that the sequence $\sqrt{n}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$ is equidistributed mod 1. However, I need a reference to this result. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: A tangentially related paper: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2060024

Comment: How do you do it without Weyl?

Comment: @Rivin: See here http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/weyl.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fejer's theorem:  If $w(t)$ is a function with continuous first and second derivatives whose signs are eventually constant, and if $t \cdot w'(t)$ goes to infinity for $t$ to infinity, and $w(t)/t$ goes to zero, then $(w(n): n=1,2,3,...)$ is uniformly distributed.

In particular, for any fixed $b>0$ and $\alpha$ between $0$ and $1$, $b\cdot n^\alpha$ is uniformly distributed.

Reference: 
Hlawka, The theory of uniform distribution, page 23.   Certainly also in Kuipers-Niederreiter, which I do not have here at the moment. 
(EDIT: After a bit of prodding, Google helped me to find Theorem 2.5 on page 13 in Kuipers-Niederreiter: If the sequence of differences $b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges monotonically to zero, and $n b_n$ diverges to infinity, then $a_n$ is u.d. mod 1.)

Comment: Do the proofs of those theorems use the Weyl criterion?

Answer (score 4):

My favorite reference on this is G. Polya and G. Szego, Problems and Theorems in Analysis,
vol. 1, second part,  Chap IV, section 4, see for example problem 174.